# How to add REAL ADS for admob? Android

Tags: android, admob

I added test ads, and everything ok, but how to add REAL ADS on my program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is a bit vague.

Are you saying you have an adMob publisher Id, have the admob-sdk-android.jar integrated in your project, have added the attrs.xml, and are using the com.admob.android.ads.AdView view to get test ads and now want to know how to get AdMob to serve up real ads?

If so, it's pretty obvious how to do that from the AdMob publisher controls page:  (if you have a publisher Id already) Or..use help link there and see the content about Publishing for your Android app.

If youre asking how to get started using the AdMob SDK with your project, you might try: http://developer.admob.com/wiki/Android

I found it pretty painless. Hope that helps.

Comment: AdManager.setTestDevices( new String[] { AdManager.TEST_EMULATOR, "FF7*******************" } );

Comment: i use this code, and only test ads show up, how to show up real ads?

Comment: If you are calling setTestDevices, then I would expect it to only show test ads.  You need to stop calling that code to get real ads.